# DataBricks adds # MAGIC in front of every python notebook line

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

My setup consist git repository connected to Azure DataBricks, this allows to develop databricks python notebooks in PyCharm, push to repo and run updated notebook in DataBricks UI.

Whenever I make change of notebook file from WebUI and do the commit, all lines in notebook file are prepended with # MAGIC:

```
# Databricks notebook source
%pip install -r "../requirements.txt"

import os
```

becomes:

```
# Databricks notebook source
# MAGIC %pip install -r "../requirements.txt"
# MAGIC 
# MAGIC import os
```

How to fix commits from Azure DataBricks to not change file on push?

Answer (score 3):

This is related to the way Azure DataBricks mixes [magic commands](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html#set-default-language) and python code.
When notebook (from Azure DataBricks UI) is split into separate parts, one containing only magic commands `%sh pwd` and others only python code, committed file is not messed up.

From text file, separate parts looks as follows:

```
# Databricks notebook source
# MAGIC %sh pwd
# COMMAND --------

<python code goes here>
```